# Make new files group-writable?

Tags: linux, filesystems

Is there a way to configure a Linux directory such that any time anyone in the group that owns that directory creates a file in the directory, that file will be writable by anyone in that group?  I'd also like to apply this configuration to all of that directory's subdirectories.

Thanks.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12842/make-all-new-files-in-a-directory-accessible-to-a-group

Answer (score 1):

The link Iain provided points to the right solution.

Use `setgid` ([Set Group ID](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Directory-Setuid-and-Setgid.html)) on the directory.  Then any new files created will be "owned" by that group. You can use either of these commands;

```
chmod +6000 /path/to/directory
chmod g+s   /path/to/directory
```